# Java wrapper for Sencha Touch

Tags: java, javascript, sencha-touch

I would like to work with Sencha Touch, but there is a small problem: I don't know JavaScript or how I would begin using Sencha Touch in JavaScript.

I already have a commercial license for Sencha Ext GWT and develop applications with it in Java.

What I need is Sencha Touch wrapped as a Java component or some guides on how to make my own Java wrapper for Sencha Touch.

I have looked at GWT4Touch, but it does not meet my requirements.

Can someone help me?

Comment: your best bet is to ask on the sencha touch forums... http://www.sencha.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?91-Sencha-Touch-2.x-Discussion

Comment: I already did, but didn't get the answer that I wanted. I would like to hear what the people on this forum have to say.

Comment: Unfortunately there is simply nothing in the market which does this right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had the same issue a few weeks back. I didn't knew Javascript but I wanted to use Sencha Touch for prototyping(work related). I came across this book "[Sencha Touch Mobile JavaScript Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849515107)":

Actually if you read this book developing apps with Sencha touch is not that hard. I was able to develop a prototype in a week where I built UI pages using Panels, toolbars , MVC,  remote proxies. I even integrated all this with Java Spring and Freemarker templates.

Here is the Store code to call the remote ajax proxy:

```
proxy: {
        id: 'proxyID',
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '../api/sampleRestJsonAPI',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        }
```

You have to setup Java Spring (With MVC) so that when your code makes a call to the remote proxy it gives you something like:

```
{"data": {"field1":"value1", "field2":"value2"}}
```

Basically it should be a valid Json with the root you have specified in your store. The url config option might change based on how you structure your folders in your web app.

So with this I do all the heavy duty data processing in the Java Layer and keep the js layer very light.

Here is a good article on [REST IN SPRING 3](http://blog.springsource.org/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/)

Comment: Can you please give me some examples of how you integrated Sencha Touch into Java/Java Spring Framework? Where on the Internet did you learn how to do that?
I am thinking of making my own wrappers for basic components like panels, buttons, scroll bars etc.

Answer (score 1):

What requirements are those?  We would be very interested in your input; perhaps there is something we can help you with.  Just ask in the Emitrom forums :-)

For those that may not know off hand what GWT4Touch is, it is precisely what the question calls for: a Java API for Sencha Touch.  We are re-branding it as Touch4j, so you may start seeing that name thrown around.

Check the demo at gwt4touch2-demo.appspot.com, or download the API from emitrom.com/gwt4touch and give it a try.

Comment: We just released Touch4j 2.0 RC.  Get it fresh from http://bit.ly/tg4lFo and please post in the Emitrom forum if you have specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

What are your requirements that make GWT4Touch unsuitable? GWT4Touch seems to do a pretty good job if you want to write Java to create Sencha Touch applications.